# Android: Generating Elliptic Curve KeypPair

Tags: java, android, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to implement key generation based on Eliptic Curves Diffie Hellman. Now I wanted to specify my Eliptic Curve by myself, so I took the parameters  [from here.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/NIST_Koblitz_Curves_Parameters)

The code which I wrote to implement this:

```
public void createKey(){

        // base point (generator???)
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger("2fe13c0537bbc11acaa07d793de4e6d5e5c94eee8", 16);
        BigInteger y = new BigInteger("289070fb05d38ff58321f2e800536d538ccdaa3d9", 16);

        // the order of generator
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger("5846006549323611672814741753598448348329118574063", 10);

        // curves coefficients
        BigInteger ab = new BigInteger("1", 2);

        // curves cofactor
        BigInteger h = new BigInteger("2", 10);

        // exponents of the equotation
        int[] ks = {7, 6, 3};

        ECFieldF2m ecField = new ECFieldF2m(163, ks);
        // Elliptic curve
        EllipticCurve ec = new EllipticCurve(ecField, ab, ab);

        // GENERATOR POINT
        ECPoint g = new ECPoint(x, y);

        // Parameter specs?
        ECParameterSpec ecps = new ECParameterSpec(ec , g , n, h.intValue());

    try {
        // get keypair
        KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA");
        kg.initialize(ecps, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair kp = kg.generateKeyPair();
        Log.d("SECLIENT"+type,kp.getPublic().toString());
        Log.d("SECLIENT"+type,kp.getPrivate().toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

At this point, the code compiles. However it fails in the try_catch block where it has to generate the KeyPair.

The Error Message is:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create EC KeyFactory: unhandled field class java.security.spec.ECFieldF2m`

Does anyone have this problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried with an Fp curve? Or is that outside requirements? Oh, and welcome to SO, hell of a question to start off with.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't come across the same exact problem you are having butsince you are using EC in Android and having a weird RuntimeException, I'll leave you my 2 cents. Hope it helps.

I had another weird error (OEM related)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0f06707b:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:UNKNOWN_GROUP
```

while trying to use

```
KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH);
```

What happened to me was that I was adding `SpongyCastle` as a `SecurityProvider`, doing this:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

And for some devices everything worked as expected but in others some device (namely LGE Nexus 5) I got the exact same exception.

What fixed it for me was changing the way I add SpongyCastle and doing:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

Comment: Also, Why do you say you are trying out Diffie-Hellman? You are using `"ECDSA"` which is for Digital Signatures. Diffie-Hellman is for secure key exchanges.